# Constraints of subviews not apply when initial loading time UITableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, constraints

I am using  UITableViewCell dynamic heights. [image]

I have set the height constraint for too view and changing the constraint inside cellforRowAtIndex if some condition being satisfied. When initially loads the table this is the result im getting. But when im scrolling the gap between too 2 buttons becomes normal but initially its like no gap bein set. How can I overcome this? Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: this is because of reuseidentifier of UITableViewCell. Your constraint changes will not impact the original cell UI when reuseidentifier is called

Comment: @SharpkitsInnovations How can I overcome this problem?